# Сборка JS проекта с помощью Jenkins

Tags: node.js, vue.js, typescript, jenkins

Имеется проект: клиентская часть - vue.js, серверная - node.js (пишем на TypeScript). Храним код в bitbucket. Столкнулись с проблемой, что тайпинги для клиента и сервера конфликтуют между собой; было принято решение разбить на разные репозитории. Теперь думаем, как можно "прикрутить" CI (Jenkins), но настораживает, что 2 отдельных репозитория. Есть ли возможность какой-то автоматической сборки клиентской и серверной части прямиком на сервер (даже вариант с bat и sh файлами подойдет)? Или стоит рассмотреть Docker? Хочется получить совета от тех, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: ну, создайте две задачи. в чём именно у вас проблема — из вопроса, увы, не ясно.

Comment: Вполне стандартный кейс, когда клиент и сервер в разных репах, если вопрос в том как объединить сборки чтобы к серверной части подселить клиентскую - есть варианты, можно позависеть от артефакта клиента и просто скопировать при сборке сервера из зависимостей